# How is vertical sync done in YPbPr component video

Tags: video

All the literature I have read about YPbPr component discusses only the horizontal sync, but I have not found anything about vertical sync.

Comment: Field sync is electrically the same as line sync but with very different timings. In essence it is a 32 odd microsecond pulse (So half a line duration) with the datum edge being the falling edge, repeated over 5 lines, but there are some subtle points having to do with avoiding DC offsets so the black restoration circuits work correctly. See http://www.batsocks.co.uk/readme/video_timing.htm for the details that I am not going to repeat here.

Comment: Technically, the link you posted is about composite, not component. Are you saying that they have the same sync technique?

Comment: The Y (luminance) in YPbPr *is* monochrome analog video, sync signals and all. It's what remains when you take composite video and remove the chroma subcarrier from it. S-Video is Y + still modulated chroma on two separate conductors, YPbPr is Y + demodulated chroma (Pb, Pr) on three separate conductors. Analog RGB is entirely different and has several implementations for the synchronization signals.

Comment: Yep, you can hook Y up to a black and white composhite monitor and it will display a picture actually somewhat better then hooking composite up would (No interference from the not present croma subcarrier).